# Duplicate Array Listing

Tags: java, android, arrays

Ive been working on a simple directory scan that shows text files, than then prints the output in to a text area. How ever for somereason it will duplicate the output if i try to use it again
below is the public array:

```
public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                    getfile(listFile[i]);

                } else {
                    if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                        fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return fileList;
    }
```

Here is the onclick button code

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + user_inputfilename); //"searches what the userinput"
                            getfile(root);
                            for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
                                newText.append(fileList.get(i).getName()+"\n");
                            }
```

I really dont know what ive done wrong? Is there a way to clear the array? anyhelp would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be looking recursively in subdirectories too? In any case, try this. Where you were calling `getFiles(dir)` do `fileList = getTextFilesRecursively(dir)` instead:

```
  public ArrayList<File> getTextFilesRecursively(File dir) {
    return getTextFilesRecursively(dir, new ArrayList<>());
  }

  private ArrayList<File> getTextFilesRecursively(File dir, ArrayList<File> textFiles) {
    File[] allFilesAndFoldersInDir = dir.listFiles();

    if(textFiles == null) {
      textFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    if (allFilesAndFoldersInDir != null && allFilesAndFoldersInDir.length > 0) {
      for (File fileOrFolderInDir : allFilesAndFoldersInDir) {
        if (fileOrFolderInDir.isDirectory()) {
          getTextFilesRecursively(fileOrFolderInDir, textFiles);
        } else if (fileOrFolderInDir.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
          textFiles.add(fileOrFolderInDir);
        }
      }
    }

    return textFiles;
  }
```

I believe your underlying issue was `fileList.add(listFile[i]);` because `fileList` was scoped outside of the method and was being reused and appended to. Now we use `textFiles` instead, which should be empty each time the method is first called. A simpler fix would be to do `fileList = new ArrayList<>()` immediately before you call `getFiles(dir);`, however the code above is far better.

Comment: Thank you in such a donut. This code is a better solution. Thank you for your help.